# Return Value Between Classes

Tags: c#

How do I get a button click on a form to send the return of a called method to another class? Here is the pseudo code of what I have and any help would be greatly appreciated...

[Class Library]

```
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    namespace Auto
    {
        GUID Info
        public interface IAuto
    {
        string SendToOtherApp();

    }

    COM Info
    public class Auto : IAuto
    {

        public string tbox1;
        NAVForm frm1 = new NAVForm();

        public Auto()
        {
        }

        public string SendToOtherApp()
        {
            frm1.ShowDialog();
            tbox1 = NAVForm.UseThis();
            return tbox1;
        }
    }
}
```

[Form]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Auto
{
    public partial class NAVForm : Form
    {
        public NAVForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NAVForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            UseThis(textBox1.Text);

        }
        public string UseThis(string txt)
        {
            if (txt.Trim().Length != 0)
            {
                return txt;
            }
            else
            {
                return "didn't work";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the return value from public string UseThis(string txt) into public string SendToOtherApp() which is visible to the other system that is calling this.

I am obviously new to C# so I am also very open to an overall critique of the project and best practices.

Comment: do you know how to access functions of other classes?

Comment: Your form will need visibility to the `Auto` class.  Either it should be passed to the `NAVForm`'s constructor, or it should instantiate `Auto` as its own field.

Comment: Not sure if this is homework or not, but my hint will be to get and keep a reference to an instance of `IAuto` for you to call methods on...

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "SendToOtherApp() which is visible to the other system that is calling this"? Are these on two separate assemblies?

Comment: This is not homework, it is being called from our ERP (the other system). The goal is when this is called, a form opens, the user enters text, then clicks "Send" and the form closes and returns the text from the textbox to our ERP. Since this is my first real venture into C# this is how far I have gotten. If anyone feels there is some sample code, or a blog that goes over this that would be great, I am also open to some pseudo code additions to where I may be missing calls or instantiations.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done and it works great. In our ERP I run the codeunit, which calls the automation variable which is tied to the "OpenThis()" method. My form opens, I enter text in the textbox, click OK, it closes the from and the ERP pops a messagebox displaying the text from the message box. What do you C# experts think about this build? I am very interested in your thoughts on this solution so please let me know.

Class Library.....

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace NavAutomation
{
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    [Guid("5D83B4FE-45E6-410E-A075-AD635F5F0354")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface INavAutomation
    {
        string HelloWorld();
        object OpenThis();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("B7806CE5-862A-4407-9A3E-14CE8A9FB83A")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class NavAutomation : INavAutomation
    {
        public NavAutomation()
        {
        }

        public object OpenThis()
        {
            using (var form = new NAVForm())
            {
                var result = form.ShowDialog();
                return form.RetVal1;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Form.....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace NavAutomation
{
    public partial class NAVForm : Form
    {

        public NAVForm()

        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NAVForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public string RetVal1 { get; set; }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Trim().Length != 0)
            {
                this.RetVal1 = textBox1.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                this.RetVal1 = "didn't work";
            }
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if i got your goals right but here is the code that when called from a from, shows another modal form with a textbox, you enter a value into that textbox and close this modal form to find that value in that textbox returned to the first form that called for the show of the modal form.

CLASS LIBRARY

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Auto
{

    public interface IAuto
    {
        string SendToOtherApp();
    }

    public class Auto : IAuto
    {
        public string tbox1;
        NAVForm frm1 = new NAVForm();

        public Auto()
        {
        }

        public string SendToOtherApp()
        {
            frm1.ShowDialog();
            tbox1 = frm1.UseThis(frm1.textBox1.Text);
            return tbox1;
        }
    }
}
```

A FROM THAT CALLS TO SHOW A MODAL FORM

```
namespace Auto
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Auto auto = new Auto();
            string returnedString = auto.SendToOtherApp(); // the string filled at the modal form text boxed will be returned to this variable
        }

    }
```

THE FORM THAT WILL BE SHOWED AS MODAL FORM

```
namespace Auto
{
    public partial class NAVForm : Form
    {
        public NAVForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string UseThis(string txt)
        {
            if (txt.Trim().Length != 0)
            {
                return txt;
            }
            else
            {
                return "didn't work";
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UseThis(textBox1.Text);
        }

    }
}
```

Please note that the access modifier of textBox1 at NAVForm should be set to public in order for it to be visible to class Auto

Let me know if i misunderstood something to correct it.